# CSS Transition not working when removing class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using using css transition to add an animated effected to my links when they are hovered over.

One of links needs to be underlined by default i.e when no other link is hovered over, it should remain underlined and when other links are hovered over, the underline in the first link should be removed. I have achieved this with jQuery by adding and removing a classs however, the animated effect is lost. Is there a way to get back this animated effect on the first link?

Also when the underline from the first link is removed, all other links seem to move up?

```js
$(".c-f, .i-c, .c-u").hover(function() {
 $('.o-c').removeClass("default-underline");
}, function() {
    $('.o-c').addClass("default-underline");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.pivot-nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.pivot-nav li a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pivot-nav li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.default-underline:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.pivot-nav li a:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.default-underline:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  position: relative !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pivot-nav">
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="o-c default-underline" href="#">Our Company</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="c-f" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="i-c" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="c-u" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because you are removing the class which has `transition` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use CSS-only:

> Remove the *underline* from the preselected element if:
>
> - we're hovering the entire UL
> - we're not hovering the preselected element

```css
.pivot-nav:hover a.default-underline:not(:hover):after {
  width: 0;
}
```

Example

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.pivot-nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.pivot-nav li a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pivot-nav li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.pivot-nav:hover a.default-underline:not(:hover):after {
  width: 0;
}

.pivot-nav li a.default-underline:after,
.pivot-nav li a:hover:after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pivot-nav">
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="default-underline" href="#">Our Company</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly and such a simple solution. Thank you